# Is it possible to have a Voice and Video call feature for a Facebook page messenger app that I created in my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on implementing **Facebook PAGE messenger** for my site and I want to add a feature that I can call **Facebook User** who message my **Facebook PAGE**. I already search on google about this matter but still no luck. is this possible to do?

If not possible do you have any suggestion how can i call the **Facebook User** and how can I implement it in my site.

Thank you in advance happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using Facebook provided API's.

However you can send the user a Call button with your businesses phone number which they can one-click to call you.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/call/